# JS FileReader ArrayBuffer to Byte[] to pass contents of a file

Tags: javascript, typescript, filereader

I have a file upload area in my application, it allows uploads of images, .doc, .docx and pdf.

I need to pass the contents of the file in a byte[] to my api so that it can store the file.

I have tried to convert from ArrayBuffer to Uint8Array but i have not been successful.

Here is my code for reading the file and obtaiing the required information

Any help would be appreciated.

```
           let myFile = ev.target.files[0];
            if(myFile.size > 0){
                let reader = new FileReader();
                var fileByteArray = [];
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(myFile);
                reader.onloadend = (ev) => {                    
                        var uintArray = new Uint8Array(reader.result.toString().length);
                        //var arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(reader.result);
                        //var array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
                    let resourceModel = new AddForumThreadResourceRequestModel({
                        contentType: myFile.type,
                        fileName: myFile.name,
                        fileContent: uintArray
                    });                   
                    console.log(resourceModel);
                    this.forumApi.AddThreadResource(resourceModel).subscribe(
                        data => {
                            if(data != null || data == true){
                                this.errorCtrl.presentToast("New resource has been added to the thread"); 
                        }                                    
                    });

            }
```

Comment: There is no such thing as `byte[]` in JS. Is that a TypeScript thing?

Comment: What error are you getting? What does not work?

Comment: It should be just `uintArray = new Uint8Array(reader.result)` - no `toString`, no length. `result` is a buffer already.

Comment: @Bergi When i tried this previously i got an error: "string | ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ArrayBuffer | ArrayLike<number>"

Comment: TypeScript doesn't seem to know that the `result` type will be `ArrayBuffer` when you are calling `.readAsArrayBuffer()`, it assumes all possible outcomes. Just add an explicit cast.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use argument of `load` event:

```
reader.onload = (e) => {                           
    var uintArray = new Uint8Array(reader.result);

    let resourceModel = new AddForumThreadResourceRequestModel({
        contentType: myFile.type,
        fileName: myFile.name,
        fileContent: uintArray
    });                    
    console.log(resourceModel);
    this.forumApi.AddThreadResource(resourceModel)
        .subscribe( data => {
            if(data != null || data == true){
                this.errorCtrl.presentToast("New resource has been added to the thread"); 
            }                                    
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, when i try evt.target i do not get the same options that are shown in your example above.
I get:
1)addEventListener
2)dispatchEvent. 
There is no evt.target.result available to me, any ideas?

Comment: @Smithy I've edited an `event` and other code. Please, see my updated reply.

Comment: What is `getB64Str`? Also I don't see why OP would need a baese64 string, he's asking for a byte array.

Comment: @Bergi thanks, you are right. I've edited an answer. Please, see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, I removed my downvote now that the answer is no longer wrong